# How to make my API method GET through id connect with my html form on view - Laravel 8

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravel-8, getmethod

**Hi guys! Hope you can help me out with this:**
**-  So i have this code in my API controller:**
[API controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOrJ.png)

**-This route in my API route:**
[API route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d8Lh.png)

**-And this on my view (only the part im having problems with):**
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI5GD.png)

ps: the line of form action is correctly seperated, where it says ..."get"action... , i just put it like that here because of space.
Q.: When i use the route to GET all the data from the database my output is a json file with everything in it, but when i use this route to only get the data of one movie (in my case it's a DB of movies) the output is an empty JSON file, even tho the method works on postman. Can you help me out ? Thank you
[MY OUTPUT , of the empty json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLxuH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a form with getting method the form data will be appended in Query Parameter.

> `/search/titulo` -> it is wrong. the titulo word is not dynamic keyword.

You get your dynamic search keyword in *titulo* keyword after `?titulo=avenger`

Use the request function to get the query parameter value

```
$seach = request()->get('titulo');
```

You should change your search to get a route to only `/search?keyword=avenger` like this.

**Full example**

In your blade file

```
<form action"{{ route('search') }}" method="get">
     <input name="titulo">
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

In your route file

```
Route::get('/search', [YourControllerName::class, 'methodname'])->name('search');
```

In your controller File: Where you handle the searched keyword

```
public function search() {
     $search = request()->get('titulo'); // Get the searched keyword value
     $result = ModelName::where('titulo', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
     return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i don't understand where should i put this exactly :                                                                                                 $seach = request()->get('titulo');    And where should i put this: /search?keyword=avenger